# Solving $x' = Ax$ for real $x$ where $A$ is a matrix with complex eigen values

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, systems-of-equations

I have the following linear differential equation system:

$$x' = A x$$ 
where
$$ A = \left( \begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 0 & 0 \\
3 & 1 & -2 \\
2 & 2 & 1 \end{array} \right) $$

I have computed the eigenvalues and eigen vectors, which are:

$$\lambda_1 = 1 \qquad \qquad v_1 =(2,-2,3)$$
$$\lambda_2 = 1 + 2i \qquad \qquad v_2 = (0,-i,1)$$
$$\lambda_3 = 1 - 2i \qquad \qquad v_3 = (0,i,1)$$

Now, the theory on my book gives the following functions as a base of the solutions of the linear system:

$$ \phi_i(t) = e^{t \lambda_i} \sum_{i=0}^{n_i-1} \dfrac{t^k}{k!}(A - \lambda_i I_n)^k v_i$$

where $n_i$ is the multiplicity of each eigenvalue. Using this formula, I get the following functions as a base of solutions from my problem:

$$\phi_1(t) = e^t (2,-2,3) \qquad \phi_2(t) = e^{(1+2i)t} (0,-i,1) \qquad \phi_3(t) = e^{(1-2i)t}(0,i,1)$$

Nevertheless, I am interested only in real solutions. I have noticed than $\phi_2(t),\phi_3(t)$ are conjugates, so i think adding them or sustracting them (and iI think I should be able to do so without problems, given that those are a base of a vector space) which would give me the real solution I am interesting in in form of sines and cosines.

Am I right? How would I do that in this particular example?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can indeed take $(\phi_1,\phi_2+\phi_3,i^{-1}(\phi_2-\phi_3))$ for a base of real  solutions.